# Static priority queue of pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, priority-queue

I have a class foo, and inside the class, I need a static priority queue bar that holds pointers to some number of foo objects, and the foo object also has a private member buzz that will hold the weight of the objects when compared.

So far, I have tried the following:

```cpp
class foo{
private:
    // some stuff
    int buzz;
public:
    // some more stuffs
    static bool compare (const foo* l, const foo* r){
        return l->buzz < r->buzz;
    }
    static std::priority_queue<foo*, std::vector<foo*>, foo::compare> bar;
};
```

But I get this error in clang:

> template argument for template type parameter must be a type

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997104/priority-queue-with-pointers-and-comparator-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670882/priority-queue-of-pointers-c) but could not get my head around how to do it or what i was doing wrong.

Comment: The third argument is supposed to be a functor type, not a function pointer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux could you please help me correct it? i don't know how to pass a function type to this one.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I thought that too but wouldn't creating an operator only work on the object but not the pointer?

Comment: You're right, I misread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [`std::priority_queue` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue),
the 3rd template argument `Compare` is:

> A Compare type providing a strict weak ordering.

A function pointer (like you used) cannot be used for the compare type.
One way to supply a compare type is via a class with **`opertor()`** (preferably a `const` one):

```
#include <queue>

class foo {
private:
    int buzz;
public:
    // Our compare type:
    struct Compare
    {
        bool operator()(const foo* l, const foo* r) const 
                       { return l->buzz < r->buzz; }
    };

    //--------------------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvv-----
    static std::priority_queue<foo*, std::vector<foo*>, foo::Compare> bar;
};
```